# Is it possible to generate simultaneous touch events in the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, touch, ios-simulator

From time to time we get bug reports with our iOS iPad application where the steps to reproduce require 2 buttons to be pressed simultaneously (or at least within a very short space of time, a tenth of a second or less).

To reproduce these bugs I have to use a real device rather than the simulator. This is fine, but also a bit of an annoyance (as I type this I'm waiting for ~10k files to copy over to the documents folder of my app on my device to get it up to date, will likely take an hour or so longer).

Ideally I'd like to be able to reproduce these issues using the simulator, so my question is whether it is possible to generate 2 touch events near enough simultaneously using the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold down Option in the Simulator you get a second "finger". If you also hold down Shift you can move around both fingers. This is usually meant to test pinch gestures.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I wanted. Interestingly the order in which  the 2 touch events are handled seems to be random (whether this is an artefact of our app code or the library code I'm not sure). Either way it was very useful for debugging the issue